# Can I do universal instantiation on this predicate?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Can I do universal instantiation on the following predicate :

$ \forall x\;S(x)\; \lor\; \forall x\;L(x)$ become $S(c)\lor L(c)$

or is it has to be $\forall x\; ((S(x) \lor L(x))$ to be able to do the instantiation ?

Comment: It is certainly possible in "standard" FOL, but I don't think you will ever see it applied in analysis,  geometry, or any kind of algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's legitimate. In natural deduction, assume $\forall x\,S(x)$; then you can instantiate that with $c$ to derive $S(c)$, and from that you can derive $S(c) \lor L(c)$. Similarly, from the assumption $\forall x\,L(x)$ you can derive $S(c) \lor L(c)$.

Thus, by assuming $\forall x\,S(x) \lor \forall x\,L(x)$ you can derive $S(c) \lor L(c)$; so 
$$
(\forall x\,S(x) \lor \forall x\,L(x)) \to (S(c) \lor L(c))
$$
is valid.

Another way to see it: from $(\forall x\,S(x) \lor \forall x\,L(x))$ you can infer the weaker sentence $\forall x(S(x) \lor L(x))$, and then instantiate *that* with $c$.

Comment: But isn't it the case that we can not distribute the universal quantifier over disjunction ?

Comment: You can't distribute it *in the other direction*: you can't go from $\forall x(P(x)\lor Q(x))$ to $\forall x P(x)\lor \forall x Q(x)$ — for example, take $Q = \neg P$. But if $\forall x P(x)\lor \forall x Q(x)$, then (the interpretation of) either $P$ or $Q$ is the entire universe, so their union is the entire universe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do universal instantiation here. Technically, applying universal instantiation (twice!) gives $S(c)\vee L(c')$ but you can take them to be the same. This is because
 $$(\forall x S(x)\vee\forall x L(x))\Rightarrow (\forall x(S(x)\vee L(x)))$$